# How can I prepopulate an AutoHotkey InputBox prompt?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm running AutoHotkey 1.0.48.05 on Windows 7.

I have this script:

```
::sw::
    InputBox, providedString, SVN Switch, Switch the current directory to where?
    if NOT ErrorLevel
    {
        Send svn switch %providedString%{Enter}
    }
Return
```

So I if type `sw{Enter}` in PowerShell (or anywhere), I'll be prompted by a text box.  Currently that text box is blank.

How can I prepopulate it with a particular string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax for `Inputbox`:

```
InputBox, OutputVar [, Title, Prompt, HIDE, Width, Height, X, Y, Font, Timeout, Default]
```

So what you want is to add a Default value:

```
::sw::
    InputBox, providedString, SVN Switch, Switch the current directory to where?,,,,,,,,<a particular string>
    if NOT ErrorLevel
    {
        Send svn switch %providedString%{Enter}
    }
Return
```

Comment: Wow, I'd looked at the docs (http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InputBox.htm) but somehow hand't seen that. Thanks.